# Permutation OTP perfect secrecy proof

Tags: cryptography

Let $M$ be a finite message space. Recall that a permutation on $M$ is a bijective function on $M^2$.
Assume that permutations can be encoded/decoded and transferred efficiently. Prove that the
following scheme has perfect secrecy:

- KeyGen : Sample a permutation $\pi$ from $M$ uniformly at random, from the space of all possible permutations, and return it as key.
- $Enc(m, \pi):$ Return $c = \pi(m)$
- $Dec(c, \pi):$ Return $\pi^{-1}(c)$

How to prove the above scheme following OTP perfect secrecy proof? I don't know the expression of KeyGen.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to review the bit "bijective function *M.2*". I think it should be $M^2$ but I was not sure so I did not change it.

Comment: @user79161 I find it more likely that they had copy-pasted, and the "2." refers to being the second question...

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the incorrect formatting. This is the first time I have asked a question on StackExchange.

Comment: How does your text define perfect secrecy?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).